# How to set up JAVA_HOME correctly?

Tags: java, windows

Hello I'm trying to set up a JDK 8

I followed these instructions:

- Browse to the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.x_y folder on your system and copy the path to the folder.
- Open Control Panel > System>Advanced System Settings.
- On the Advanced tab click Environment Variables.
- Locate the System variables section and click New.
- Enter JAVA_HOME in the Variable name field and paste the folder path you copied into the Variable value field.
- Click OK to close the dialog.
- Click on Path variable in the **System variables ** section and click Edit.
- Click **New **and type %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the available space.
- Close all dialog windows.

Then it says to Open a new  Command Prompt window, and run the following command:

`C:\Users\manthony>javac -version`

Which should result in `javac 1.8.0_91`

But I get `javac 16.0.1`

My `JAVA_HOME` variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv9o.png)

My `PATH` variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X6UR.png)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: That C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath smells bad. I think it's another JDK that gets read before yours.

Comment: Forget about `JAVA_HOME`. When you care about which Java gets executed when you run `java` on the command line then `PATH`  must be set up appropriately (to mention the path to the correct executable before any other).

Comment: @JoachimSauer that's supposedly what he did when setting %JAVA_HOME%/bin in his Path. However, I think the Path contain (before this entry) another entry where there is a java.exe that is called when trying to do java --version

Comment: thanks for responding. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @wsrog if you type "where java" on a command line, what path does it point to? I'm ready to guess is the one under Oracle/Java/javapath. If that's the case, you simply need to remove that variable from the Path (if you're not using it, of course) so that the other one can take over

Comment: *Click New and type %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the available space.* Not what I do. *Edit* PATH and **Pre**pend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to the PATH

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` isn't used by Java. Only by other things like Tomcat. I haven't set `JAVA_HOME` as an environment variable for over 20 years.

Comment: That's true. Perhaps the OP has a reason for setting it though

Comment: @user207421 what the OP is doing though is not bad at all. He's declaring his JAVA_HOME, then he's referencing it in the Path to point to the java executable. Doing that guarantees that Java used (either directly by java command or by other executables such as mvn or gradle) is uniform, because it reads from the JAVA_HOME, and when an update has to be made can be done directly and only at JAVA_HOME level. The only issue is having is that the java.exe is overriden by another variable of his own Path.

Answer (score 0):

on windows, execute "where java" on command terminal to find out how your os is finding the java binary, if it is using another path, (my guess is oracle/javaPath), you either delete the latter or place your preferred path before the other one in the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the Java paths set by Oracle previously when you installed java.
[image]

either swap shortcuts in the folders they are pointing to with ones from you desired version, or uninstall your previously installed jdk/jre, or just take those out of your PATH.

FYI, they get called first when you run JAVA commands as they are ahead of other entries in your PATH.